# Multilingual code captions for user functions

Tags: front-end, packages, user-interface, localization

*Mathematica* 11 features [multilingual code captions](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/multilingual-functionality/code-captions.html) for built-in symbols.  How do I define code captions in different languages for my own functions which may go into a *Mathematica* application/package?

Comment: Coudn't find anything relevant in the Options Inspector, neither does anything related show up if you do a Show Expression on the cell that has a translation. Nothing in the stylesheets that would give me a clue either.

Comment: `$InstallationDirectory / SystemFiles / FrontEnd / SystemResources / FunctionalFrequency / *.m` files seem to be related.

Comment: @Kuba Indeed, it seems the translations are there, but simply adding an entry there doesn't suffice, and changing an existing translation there doesn't change the translation in the Frontend

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I agree; the front end doesn't draw the captions from there.